# change multiple array values to a value

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new at programming (using python) and have a simple question. 
I have this list containing different elements

```
tegn = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and another list

```
guess = ["a", "c", "c"]
```

I want the guess list to change to ["a", "a", "a"]. My attempt is:

```
guess[-2:] = tegn[0]
```

But that makes it ["a", "a"], thus removing an element. How do I do it without removing an element?

EDIT:

the guess list will change a lot during the program, since I'm making a brute force method to guess a string. So guess wil be ["a"], ["b"], ["c"] where it goes ["a", "a"], ["a", "b"] and so on

Comment: `guess = [tegn[0] for _ in tegn]`?

Comment: Can you explain the pattern that make you wanting to turn gess to `["a", "a", "a"]`? Cause as from what you explain the best solution seems `guess = ["a", "a", "a"]`

Comment: I'm making a brute force method to guess a string. Check out the edit

Answer (score 4):

You can reassign the values using list slicing:

```
guess = ["a", "c", "c"]

guess[1:] = ["a" for i in range(guess.count("c"))]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a']
```

If for some reason you are using slightly different code and a getting nested list:

```
import itertools

new_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(guess))
```

Edit:

you can use `itertools.product` to create a list of all possible pairings of `["a", "b", "c"]`:

```
from itertools import product

l = "abc"

listing = list(product(l, repeat=2))
```

Comment: This will produce a list within my list. For example a point in my code the guess list will be ["a", "c"] and with your code it will become ["a" ["a"]] which won't work with the rest of the code

Comment: @Bassusour that is very odd. I tested this solution in both Python2 and Python3 and I get a perfectly flat list. However, I added in method that you can use even if you are getting nested lists.

Comment: If you explain your problem in more detail as to why the guess list changes you may find a more robust solution.

Comment: I'm making a method that should guess it's input, using brute force method. Meaning guess changes to a, b, c then aa, ab, ac then ba, bb, bc and so on. This part of the code is the last missing part

Comment: ok there may be a better solution using a tertiary counting system in that case are the only characters a, b and c?

Comment: I'm only using a,b,c for testing. the tegn list will have a lot more characters in it, but debugging would take so much longer that way.

Comment: Your solution using permutations does not include repetitions of a character i.e [('a', 'a')].

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools to iterate over all possible products of tegn up to a given length.

```
from itertools import product

tegn = ["a", "b", "c"]
length = 3 # all products up to 3 characters long
for i in range(1, length + 1):
  for j in product(tegn, repeat=i):
    guess = list(j)
    print(guess)
# prints ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'] etc.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
for i in xrange(len(guess)):
    guess[i] = tegn[0]
```

Iterating the element in guess and update them to the first element of tegn.

EDIT:

You can specify the condition in the for loop, saying you want the value of `i` going through from 1 to the whole array:

```
start = 1
end = len(guess)
new_value = tegn[0]
for i in xrange(start, end):
    guess[i] = new_value
```

Comment: I only want to change the last two values. The first value won't stay "a" for long so this solution wouldn't fix the code in the long run